# Sonar code coverage does not reflecting on server without classes files

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, code-coverage, jacoco

I have created Maven project and created surefire-report as well jacoco report. jacoco.exec is also generated and if I upload my project on server with compiled classes then I can able to see my code coverage, but as the best practices if I omit the class files the I am not able to see the code coverage. Can someone please help me out?
Can refer the following screen-shots that will help you easily understand my problem.
If I upload my compiled class file on server,then it works fine as below,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mF7KW.png)

But I don't want to upload my complied class file as it is not best practice, so because of that I get this result,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Klwpk.png)

Comment: Tools like **jacoco** need class-files usually. Indeed, there is no need to keep class-files on the server (BTW class-files should be packaged into WAR, EAR, JAR of whatever). Just move coverage analyzing into separate Maven's goal. And execute it after tests but before deployment (like described in [Creating Code Coverage Reports for Unit and Integration Tests With the JaCoCo Maven Plugin](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/maven/creating-code-coverage-reports-for-unit-and-integration-tests-with-the-jacoco-maven-plugin/) article).

Answer (score 3):

SonarQube as well as JaCoCo require class files only at analysis time, but do not store them anywhere afterwards. While without class files SonarQube can produce some result (partial or even wrong), JaCoCo absolutely can not and requires class files.

Also should be noted that both (SonarQube in its UI, and JaCoCo in its native report without SonarQube) do show source code. Hence strange that you are fine with uploading of source code, while don't want to upload classes, but this is another story as anyway they are not uploaded/used after analysis.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.
but if my jacoco have the reports of test cases so why the class file needed again to analysis the test case. Can we fetch reports from jacoco.exec?
And does it is mandatory to include sonar.java.binaries in sonar.properties file?

Comment: @DeepakKumbhar not sure I understand what you mean by "why the class file needed again to analysis the test case", but when you execute tests with JaCoCo you get `jacoco.exec` that contains only execution information, so that it should be combined with class files to create html and xml JaCoCo native reports about code coverage. SonarQube does not import such html/xml reports, instead it takes jacoco.exec and combines with class files to create its own report, also SonarQube does class files analysis for his purposes - to find bugs.

Comment: Thanks... Can you send me sonar.properties configuration file, because i am importing sonar.java.binaries=<path of class file >, so i am not getting it properly what am i doing wrong.